# Text to speech won't work in Chrome anymore

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I like to use Apple's "Text to Speech" option (under *System Preferences* → *Dictation and Speech*) to have my computer read things to me like articles and whatnot. However, the keyboard shortcut to make this happen just suddenly stopped working properly in Google Chrome.

[image: Speech window]

Normally, you just select some text with your mouse, then press the keyboard shortcut (which I have set to <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>), and then the computer voice reads the selected text to you.

This keyboard shortcut *still* works in other applications like Finder and Firefox, but when I do so in Chrome it doesn't read the selected text - instead, it reads the `<title>`Web Page's Name`</title>` and that's it.

[image: Diagram]

If I highlight the text, right click → *Speech* → *Start Speaking*, then it'll work like normal and read the text aloud.

[image: Start speaking]

So if *that* works, then why can't I use the keyboard shortcut to use text to speech anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Upgrade/Reinstall Operating System

I recently installed **MacOS Mojave** and now the "Text to Speech" function works perfectly, just like it used to. 
While this didn't identify what was *causing* the problem, it did solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this problem for a long time but I have found the solution/problem. The text to speech function only doesn't work properly when the window isn't in fullscreen. If you click the little green dot and the left hand corner of the window you'll put the window into fullscreen mode. If the little yellow dot is not greyed out This means you are not in fullscreen mode. Looking at your screenshots It doesn't look like you're in full screen mode as the little yellow dot isn't greyed out.

I appreciate this is not the correct place to post this, But if you rely on this function as i do this information could be life-changing.